# Can't seem to retrieve stripe charge using python

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have the following python code to create a charge in stripe.

```
a_charge = stripe.Charge.create(
amount=cents, 
currency="usd",
source=token,
description="my_description",
application_fee=application_fee,
stripe_account=teacher_stripe_id
)
```

This succeeds (I think), because it shows up in my dashboard with a charge_id.
But then, immediately after in the code, the following fails:

```
stripe.Charge.retrieve(a_charge.id)
```

With error:
    No such charge: somelongstringhere

However, somelongstringhere is indeed the ID under charge details on my stripe dashboard.  So how come Stripe can't retrieve this charge?  Is this not the correct id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the charge retrieval call fails is because the charge was created on a different account.

When you create the charge:

```
a_charge = stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=cents, 
  currency="usd",
  source=token,
  description="my_description",
  application_fee=application_fee,
  stripe_account=teacher_stripe_id
)
```

you use the `stripe_account` parameter, which instructs the library to use the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) in the request. This is used to tell Stripe's API that the request is issued by your platform on behalf of one of its connected accounts.

So in order to retrieve the charge, you need to use the same `stripe_account` parameter:

```
the_same_charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(a_charge.id, stripe_account= teacher_stripe_id)
```

That said, there is little use to do this in practice. You already have the charge object in `a_charge`. If you execute the code above, you'd find that `a_charge == the_same_charge`.

More generally, when you already have an instance of a Stripe object and want to get the latest state from the API, you can use the `refresh()` method:

```
a_charge.refresh()
```

This will query the API (without you having to worry about the `stripe_account` parameter -- the instance "remembers" about it and will use it in the background) and refresh the instance's attributes with the values retrieved from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do `stripe.Charge.retrieve(a.charge.id)` immediately after creating the charge while you already have the data within `a_charge`?

It is possible that data are cached and/or broadcasted to multiple servers/databases. Newly created data may then take a few seconds to be available for reading.

Comment: I don't actually want to do it directly after - originally I was doing this in a different function and it was not working so I moved the code closer together.  However, I don't think that is the problem because I'm actually seeing a different id when I use stripe.charge.list() than the one returned - is there any reason that might be happening?

Comment: What is the ID returned ? At least, what is the prefix ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you're using here is creating a charge directly on a connected Stripe account. This is covered in Stripe's documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly).

Since the charge is on a connected account, it doesn't exist on your own Stripe account and it's expected you can't retrieve it directly. To do this, you need to pass the `Stripe-Account` header again as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header).

Your code should instead be

```
the_charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(
    id=a_charge.id,
    stripe_account=teacher_stripe_id)
```