# Stripe Direct Charge not recording

Tags: node.js, stripe-connect

I am using Node with Firebase Cloud Functions to trigger the Auth & Capture of Direct Charges with Stripe Connect.

First I create the charge, not capturing it:

```
const charge = {
    capture: false,
    amount: 1000,
    currency: "eur",
    source: token,
    metadata: {order_id: rentID, some: "foo"},
  };
return stripe.charges.create(charge, {stripe_account: customAccount} )
```

Everything goes smoothly, and I get the charge object from the callback:

```
 ch_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXgMKI7Q:
   amount: 1000
   amount_refunded:  0
   application: "some"
   captured: false
   created: 1508928708
   currency: "eur"
   id: "ch_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXgMKI7Qet"
   livemode: false
   metadata: {}
   object: "charge"
   outcome: {}
   paid: true
   refunded: false
   refunds: {}
   source: {}
   status: "succeeded"
```

I also get the charge from the appropriate webhook:

```
-KxI9Dk-LVvM8Wth1TwC: {
   api_version: "2017-08-15"
   created: 1508928708
   data:
   object: 
     amount: 1000
     amount_refunded: 0
     application: "some"
     captured: false
     created: 1508928708
     currency: "eur"
     id: "ch_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXgMKI7Qet"
     livemode: false
     metadata: {}
     object: "charge"
     outcome: {} 
     paid: true
     refunded: false
     refunds
     source
     status: "succeeded"
   id: "evt_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXPRl5bvCx"
   livemode: false
   object: "event"
   pending_webhooks: 1
   request
     id: "req_4sR247IPJCeXMU"
   type: "charge.succeeded"
}
```

However, when I want to capture the charge using

```
return stripe.charges.capture("ch_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXgMKI7Qet", {amount: 1000})
```

I get the issue:

```
Error: No such charge: ch_1BGmUCLdU1UUJ0JXgMKI7Qet
```

It is also weird because in my Stripe Dashboard I cannot see the capture recorded in the test/event category.

Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348373/cant-seem-to-retrieve-stripe-charge-using-python).
The charge is not recognized because it is not recorded in the platform account, but in the connected account directly.

So in order to capture the charge, this is what to do:

```
stripe.charges.capture(transactionID, {stripe_account: connectedAccount})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can not retrieve the charges because direct charges are made in the connected account directly.

You can retrieve the direct charges made in the connected account by initialising connected account API credentials you got while connecting to the account

stripe_secret_key and stripe_publishable_key

this way you can get access to charges made from your platform account.